# How can I access a value from one model and pass to another model in Django?

Tags: django, class, model

I have one model called Weight (filled by User input/choice) and another called Enterprise.

```
class Weight(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="weights")
    weight_of_history = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


class Enterprise(models.Model):
...
```

The weight is saved, one per user, and replaced everytime the user choose new one.

Inside the Enterprise class, I am creating an property that must get the "weight_of_history" (depending on the user, who has chosen the weight) from Weight class, but the models have no Foreign key or related name between them.

```
class Enterprise(models.Model):
...

    @property
    def ranking(self):
        
        weight_of_history = <-- HERE I NEED TO TAKE WEIGHT_HISTORY FROM THE FIRST MODEL
        THEN I COULD CALCULATE
```

How could I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use django's powerful query functionality and fetch the required objects from the db. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/) that might help you with that. Django docs are amazing, so I would recommend that you read up on queries, models, and forms to have easier time with you project.

For your example we can fetch all the weights for the user in one query by filtering the weights by user. In fact, django ORM allows for chaining filters and you can create really sophisticated queries

```
class Enterprise(models.Model):
...

    @property
    def ranking(self):
        
        weight_of_history = Weight.objects.filter(user=some_user)
```

If you do not know the user beforehand, then you can do inside the view and grab the user that makes the request and filter using this user:

```
#views.py

user_making_request = request.user
weight_of_history = Weight.objects.filter(user=user_making_request)
```

Comment: thank you. but I don't know the name of the user, I need the current user (user.request or similar)

Comment: In this case you can do inside your view.

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.